# Caching Approach On Static Variables and MVC

Tags: c#, caching, model-view-controller, static, entity

I'm trying to implement some caching approach on my MVC page like this.

```
    private static List<T> DATA = new List<T>()

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
         if(DATA.Count()==0)
          {
          FillGlobalVaribles();
          }
    }

    public JsonResult GC()
    {
         DATA = new List<T>();
    } 

    private static FillGlobalVariables()
    {
        DATA = entityObject.foo.ToList();
    }

   public JsonResult ListItems(string FilterString)
    {
      DATA.OrderBy(c=>c.ID).ToList();
     return Json(new {Result="OK",RecordSet = Data});
    }
```

I'm filling my static variable on my Controller's Index Method. And if user make some sortings some filterings will apply on DATA variable.

And i implement custom GC method if user change the page (click another  tag) ajax call to GC method and clear variables.

So my issue is ,

if DATA variable was filled and applied some filterings (some example : pure data variable contains 3000 items and filter result is 200 result) and  another user come to page DATA variable contains 200 items. But I want create new object instances for per users.

Answer (score 0):

you need to be careful using statics like this. Unless you use a lock{} statement or a mutex several different threads could try to initialize or use your List all at once. You'll end up with a mess if you're not careful.

Look into Redis - that may provide you with what you need - https://redis.io/.

Redis is an in-memory cache that you can use to store single items and lists in. Here's a small example:

```
using StackExchange.Redis;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace RedisTest
{

    class Program
    {

        #region Diagnostics

        static void w(string msg = "")
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(msg);
        }

        static void w(string fmt, params object [] p)
        {
            string msg = string.Format(fmt, p);
            w(msg);
        }

        #endregion Diagnostics




        //
        // Use of redis:
        //
        // https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Basics.md
        // https://redis.io/commands
        //


        static string string_key = "key_string";
        static string string_val = "Mary had a little lamb. She ate it.";

        static string int_key = "key_int";
        static string int_val = "100";

        static string non_existent_key = "sdlfhsfhshdfhsdf";


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
            w("Connected to Redis.");
            w();

            IDatabase redis_db = redis.GetDatabase();

            // Storage and retrieval of a string
            redis_db.StringSet(string_key, string_val);
            var redis_val = redis_db.StringGet(string_key);
            string sval = (string) redis_val;
            w("String value retrieved: {0}", sval);


            // Storage of an int; decrementing and incrementing it
            redis_db.StringSet(int_key, int_val);
            redis_db.StringDecrement(int_key, 15);
            redis_val = redis_db.StringGet(int_key);
            int iVal = (int)redis_val;
            w("Int retrieved: {0}", iVal);

            redis_db.StringIncrement(int_key, 55);
            redis_val = redis_db.StringGet(int_key);
            iVal = (int)redis_val;
            w("Int retrieved: {0}", iVal);


            // Retrieving a non-existent value
            redis_val = redis_db.StringGet(non_existent_key);
            if (redis_val.IsNull)
            {
                w("Null value retrieved.");
            }


            // Check for existence of a key

            bool b = redis_db.KeyExists(int_key);
            if (b)
            {
                w("Key {0} exists.", int_key);
            }

            b = redis_db.KeyExists(non_existent_key);
            if (!b)
            {
                w("Key {0} does not exist.", int_key);
            }




            // Delete a key
            redis_db.KeyDelete(string_key);
            redis_db.KeyDelete(int_key);

            // Delete all keys - only available from command line: https://redis.io/commands/flushdb


            w();
            redis.Close();
            redis.Dispose();
            w("Disconnected from Redis.");

            w();
            w("Hit RETURN to end.");
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }

    } // class Program

} // namespace RedisTest
```

The beauty of it is that if you have more than one server running your web site the same data can be cached between all of them using it. So all the worry of multiple threads accessing the same data is handled for you.

Hope this helps,

Adam.

Comment: Hi.  Thank you for replying my question. I tried use lock{} statement but I think it is not works.  How can i use lock statement ? Can you give little sample ?

I tried redis but i don't understand redis working principle.

Comment: Hi Toygar. Generally you're much better of steering clear of statics for MVC if you can help it. I can't say *never* use them but look for other ways first. I've edited my original answer to include a small example of using Redis - note you have to install it first.

Comment: Hi Adam i already know redis sample thanks for sharing. But how can i store my list on redis ? Like redis.push(List<T>data);

Comment: Well, you can't send a List<T> directly to it. You'd need to write your own helper methods for that. But loop through your elements and use a command such as https://redis.io/commands/linsert and https://redis.io/commands/lpop

Comment: Just where in the controller life cycle would I populate the Reddis DB? Or should I do that at startup and merely access it in the controller?

Comment: @ProfK Hi. We normally populate redis with the data if we look for it and it's not there. So, a request comes in for the data, is it in redis? No -> Calculate the data (usually load it from db) and send it to redis. Yes-> Load from redis. Either way send the data back to the client as the result. If anything happens that would change the data tell redis to delete it so it gets recalculated next time around.

Comment: Thanks, @AdamBenson. I have actually just found an example doing just that.